# Multiple styled clusters in a map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, mapbox, markerclusterer

I need to show many different points in a map. Till now, I used to create map pages with google maps. I have already created one page with a cluster but now I need more. I need something like:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markercluster-multiple-groups/

But I haven't found this in google maps. I have a problem with mapbox due I think it is not free so my company would have to pay for it. Is this possible in google maps? Or in leaflet?

I've already done some things with leaflet, if this is possible, I could use that. But I haven't found anything for leaflet neither. Could you point me to some tutorial or pages in which this kind of maps are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the [Marker Clusterer Plus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html#ClusterIconStyle) library from the Google Maps Utility Library V3? The 'Advanced Example' on the [How-to Page](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/examples.html) even demonstrates custom styling for the cluster markers.

Comment: I checked that and I was able to make it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the example that you posted uses [markercluster, Leaflet plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster). Mapbox is a well synchronized fork of Leaflet, so you can use most of Leaflet plugins with it.

In the example, this code creates a group of a color. Vanilla Markercluster plugin seems to be used for that.

```
function makeGroup(color) {
  return new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
      return new L.DivIcon({
        iconSize: [20, 20],
        html: '<div style="text-align:center;color:#fff;background:' +
        color + '">' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div>'
      });
    }
  }).addTo(map);
}
```

Look at Markercluster docs and the exmaple you mention and you should be able to build your own marker groups.

Comment: I guess you are right. I will check documentation again because we want to port all our google maps page to leaflet. With that, I think I can include multiple cluster there. Thank you too